# Hook woocommerce_thankyou doesn't receive order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

In WooCommerce, I am using a custom function hooked in `woocommerce_thankyou` action hook, to execute some code after a payment has been made. The hook works but it seems that I can't get the order.

This is the simplified code. By the looks of it `$order` isn't found:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'afterorder', 10, 1 );


function afterorder($order_id) {
    //$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $order_items = $order->get_items();
    $order_comment_list = explode('\n', $order->customer_message);
    $payment_method = $order->payment_method_title; 

    foreach( $order_items as $product ) {
        $order->add_order_note('order for '.$product['name'].' received', false);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a partially outdated and with some errors since WooCommerce 3+. Order line items are now **`WC_Order_Item_Product`** class objects.

For Order "line items" you need to use **`WC_Order_Item_Product`** available methods to get the related data, like the corresponding product title:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'afterorder', 10, 1 );
function afterorder( $order_id ) {
    // The WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    $order_comment_list = explode( '\n', $order->get_customer_note() ); // Changed

    $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method_title(); // Changed 

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $line_item ) {
        // The WC_Product object
        $product = $line_item->get_product(); // Added
        $note = 'order for '.$product->get_title().' received';// Changed
        $order->add_order_note( $note, false );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme) or in any plugin file.*

You should check may be the `WC_Order` method [`add_order_note()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html#_add_order_note) to see if you have correctly set it as you want.

Comment: Nice! Excellent answer.  It may be worth mentioning that `10, 1` are the defaults on an `add_action`, and are therefore not necessary.... `add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'afterorder' )`...

Comment: @cale_b When coding is better to set priorities and number of args, for many reasons. Is a little like strict variable declaration… But you are right both works. Thanks :)